# Не понимаю как можно задать переменные

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Не смог правильно задать переменные,нашел в интеренете вариант вот весь код:

```
import sys  # sys нужен для передачи argv в QApplication
import os  # Отсюда нам понадобятся методы для отображения содержимого директорий

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

import calc_design  # Это наш конвертированный файл дизайна

class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, calc_design.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # Это здесь нужно для доступа к переменным, методам
        # и т.д. в файле design.py
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)  # Это нужно для инициализации нашего дизайна
        self.pushButton_8.clicked.connect(self.button1)
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.button2)
        self.pushButton_7.clicked.connect(self.button3)
        # Кнопки
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.button4)
        self.pushButton_10.clicked.connect(self.button5)
        self.pushButton_6.clicked.connect(self.button6)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.button7)
        self.pushButton_9.clicked.connect(self.button8)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.button9)
        self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.button0)
        # Варианты действий
        self.pushButton_11.clicked.connect(self.buttonMinus)
        self.pushButton_12.clicked.connect(self.buttonPlus)
        self.pushButton_13.clicked.connect(self.buttonYmno)
        self.pushButton_14.clicked.connect(self.buttonDelit)
        self.pushButton_15.clicked.connect(self.Result)


     # Действия
    def buttonDelit(self, c: 'c', index: str = '')->str:
        c = '/'
        return C[c]

    def buttonYmno(self, c: 'c', index: str = '')->str:
        c = '*'
        return C[c]

    def buttonMinus(self, c: 'c', index: str = '')->str:
        c = '-'
        return C[c]

    def buttonPlus(self, c: 'c', index: str = '')->str:
        c = '+'
        return C[c]
     # Числа
    def button1(L:'b', index : int = 0, A: 'a', index : int = 0)->int:
        if c:
            b = b + str(1)
            return L[b]
        else:
            a = a + str(1)
            return A[a]
    def button2(selfl, L:'b', index : int = 0, A: 'a', index : int = 0)->int:
        if c:
            b = b + str(2)
            return L[b]
        else:
            a = a + str(2)
            return A[a]
    def button3(self, L:'b', index : int = 0, A: 'a', index : int = 0)->int:
        if c:
            b = b + str(3)
            return L[b]
        else:
            a = a + str(3)
            return A[a]
    def button4(self, L:'b', index : int = 0, A: 'a', index : int = 0)->int:
        if c:
            b = b + str(4)
            return L[b]
        else:
            a = a + str(4)
            return A[a]
    def button5(self, L:'b', index : int = 0, A: 'a', index : int = 0)->int:
        if c:
            b = b + str(5)
            return L[b]
        else:
            a = a + str(5)
            return A[a]
    def button6(self, L:'b', index : int = 0, A: 'a', index : int = 0)->int:
        if c:
            b = b + str(6)
            return L[b]
        else:
            a = a + str(6)
            return A[a]
    def button7(self, L:'b', index : int = 0, A: 'a', index : int = 0)->int:
        if c:
            b = b + str(7)
            return L[b]
        else:
            a = a + str(7)
            return A[a]
    def button8(self, L:'b', index : int = 0, A: 'a', index : int = 0)->int:
        if c:
            b = b + str(8)
            return L[b]
        else:
            a = a + str(8)
            return A[a]
    def button9(self, L:'b', index : int = 0, A: 'a', index : int = 0)->int:
        if c:
            b = b + str(9)
            return L[b]
        else:
            a = a + str(9)
            return A[a]
    def button0(self, L:'b', index : int = 0, A: 'a', index : int = 0)->int:
        if c:
            b = b + str(0)
            return L[b]
        else:
            a = a + str(0)
            return A[a]
    def Result(self, R: 'res', index: int = 0) ->int:
        if c == '*':
            d = a * float(b)
            return R[d]
        if c == '/':
            d = a / float(b)
            return R[d]
        if c == '+':
            d = a + float(b)
            return R[d]
        if c == '-':
            d = a - float(b)
            return R[d]
        # ListWidgets
        self.listWidget.clear()
        self.listWidget_2.clear()
        self.listWidget_3.clear()

        self.listWidget.addItem(R)
        self.listWidget_2.addItem(A)
        self.listWidget_3.addItem(L)
    #Выполнить функцию browse_folder

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  # Новый экземпляр QApplication
    window = ExampleApp()  # Создаём объект класса ExampleApp
    window.show()  # Показываем окно
    app.exec_()  # и запускаем приложение

if __name__ == '__main__':  # Если мы запускаем файл напрямую, а не импортируем
    main()  # то запускаем функцию main()
```

Вот ошибка:

```
File "main.py", line 50
    def button1(L:'b', index : int = 0, A: 'a', index : int = 0)->int:
               ^
SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument
```

Помогите кто шарит)))

Answer (score 1):

Данный код - описание класса `ExampleApp`, где все вложенные функции - его методы. В python методам класса необходимо явно передавать объект класса в первом аргументе сигнатуры функции в виде переменной `self`. Если посмотреть внимательно, то можно это заметить:

```py
...
def buttonDelit(self, c: 'c', index: str = '')->str:
    ...
def buttonMinus(self, c: 'c', index: str = '')->str:
    ...
def buttonPlus(self, c: 'c', index: str = '')->str:
    ...
```

А вот в сигнатуре функции вызывающей ошибку, этой переменной нет.

```py
def button1(L:'b', index : int = 0, A: 'a', index : int = 0)->int:
```

Отсюда и ошибка.

Comment: Это не помогает

Comment: Та же самая ошибка

Comment: ну вы хоть приведите исправленный код и точный текст ошибки

Comment: Так у вас еще и порядок параметров вперемежку. Сперва нужно указывать обязательные параметры без значений по-умолчанию, а потом необязательные со значениями по-умолчанию. А еще у вас аргумент `index` зачем-то два раза указан.